# How to save Columns of a grid as rows in db

Tags: c#, iterator, grid, save, radgridview

I want to save grid columns as rows in db. Please see the following image.

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/111/columnsasrows.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/111/columnsasrows.png)

Columns 'Full Package' is saved as row in db but I have make it as column. 'Package for 1' is new record, each Event Member must be saved as individual record in db. There might be more columns like this.

I need to save/update records in one go.

Thanks.

Comment: What type of grid is that? A WPF grid? An Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: RadGridView or DataGridView (.net)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might consider each member having a packages column of type xml in your database?

In Karima Sook's row the value for the XML column might look something like...

```
<packages>
<package name="Full Package" checked="true" />
<package name="Package for 1" checked="false" /></packages>
```